# SIM 900 + Arduino Mega attachGPRS problem, GPRS_READY

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm

I have connected my GSM module to my Arduino. Using AT commands I am able to connect to internet.
  Using the following link of tutorials, I tried to connect to internet
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesXivelyClient
  In this the device is showing not connected. So I tried to debug it. In the attachGPRS 
(gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD)==GPRS_READY)

gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD = 2

and GPRS_READY = 4

Why is this happening? What is GPRS_READY ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. I know english isn't you first language, but please try to rephrase it. The code you provide is also weird, with for example missing parentheses.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE! First of all, did you solve [your other question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/sim-900-arduino-mega-pin-connection-problem) yet? Also, it seems like you're relying on external code. Can you please add any relevant code? Thanks!